# Which system monitors are able to show me a non-rounded memory usage?

Tags: programming, development, memory-usage, system-monitor, memory-leak

Backstory:

I am trying to detect memory leaks in a program by viewing the memory used from the system monitor, and seeing if it rises while doing a certain activity.

System Monitor unfortunately rounds to the nearest megabyte, making small memory leaks harder to detect. Is there a system monitor that can give me a more accurate view of memory usage?

Comment: how precise it must be, and how frequent do you want it to update? 
`watch -d -c "cat /proc/meminfo"` might help you?

Comment: Kilobyte should suffice, although byte would be nice too, as certain types can be very small. 2 seconds is good though; how can I feed it an PID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`watch -n1 'ps ax -o "vsize cmd" | sort -n | tail'`

Run `ps` command with custom output format, `sort` numerically from lowest to highest memory usage, get the last few entries (optional). And run it continuously with `watch` and two single quotes to treat the piped command as literals

Comment: %mem rounds the memory, giving me the same issue I had in the op.

Comment: @Akiva try `-o "rss cmd"`

Comment: @muru That's what I was thinking about. To evaluate a memory leak he'd rather measure the virtual memory size, not the rss.

Comment: @kos But the System Monitor shows RSS by default, AFAIK.

Comment: @muru Yes I think so, in fact I think OP's method is wrong in first place

Comment: ps ax -o "size cmd"  perhaps ? man ps says size is memory size in kilobytes

Comment: I'd rather say `vsize` since it's the size of the virtual memory. That should include everything